# Angular CDK ListKeyManager differences

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, accessibility, angular-cdk

Angular [CDK a11y documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/a11y/overview#types-of-key-managers) mentions two types of `ListKeyManager`:

> There are two varieties of ListKeyManager, FocusKeyManager and
> ActiveDescendantKeyManager.
>
> **FocusKeyManager**
>
> Used when options will directly receive browser focus.
> Each item managed must implement the FocusableOption interface
>
> **ActiveDescendantKeyManager**
>
> Used when options will be marked as active
> via aria-activedescendant. Each item managed must implement the
> Highlightable interface:

This is not very informative to me and I prefer asking here to reading source, so I would like to know the difference, what are the use cases for each, so I can choose the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing ActiveDescendantKeyManager I noticed it does very little, so I did not use any of them, but wrote my own logic for key/list handling.